# Pyppeteer fails to download headless chrome when running on AWS Lambda

Tags: python, docker, aws-lambda, pyppeteer

Pyppeteer (python port of puppeteer) is trying to download linux-chrome but fails to download.

This is a python project, that I have dockerized and used serverless to deploy into an AWS Lambda. I'm using serverless to deploy the python dependencies into a lambda layer.

I can't find anything definitive on google that shows me how to setup a proper lambda for chrome browser automation using a python a runtime.

serverless

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.7

functions:
  main:
    handler: main.handler
    package:
      include:
        - src/main.py
    layers:
      - {Ref: PythonRequirementsLambdaLayer}
    environment:
      REGION_NAME: us-west-2

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: true
    zip: true
    dockerImage: mydocker:latest
    layer: true

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
```

pyppeteer

```py
        self.browser = await pyppeteer.launch({
            'headless': True,
            'args': [
                '--no-sandbox', 
                '--disabled-setuid-sandbox', 
                '--disable-dev-profile', 
                '--user-data-dir=/tmp'
            ]
        })
```

dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install curl
RUN apt-get install -y git
RUN apt-get install -y gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget

ENV REGION_NAME='us-west-2'
ENV XDG_CACHE_HOME='/tmp/.cache'
ENV PYPPETEER_HOME='tmp/'

COPY . src/

WORKDIR src

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

RUN python3 -c 'import pyppeteer; pyppeteer.chromium_downloader.download_chromium()'
```

error message

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "message": "[Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/home/sbx_user1051'",
    "trace": [
        "Traceback (most recent call last):\n",
        "  File \"/var/task/main.py\", line 18, in handler\n    result = loop.run_until_complete(main())\n",
        "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py\", line 584, in run_until_complete\n    return future.result()\n",
        "  File \"/var/task/main.py\", line 68, in main\n    ring_results = await pyp_client.get_ring_results()\n",
        "  File \"/var/task/clients/pyppeteer_client.py\", line 40, in get_ring_results\n    await self.ready_the_browser()\n",
        "  File \"/var/task/clients/pyppeteer_client.py\", line 18, in ready_the_browser\n    await self.__create_browser_instance()\n",
        "  File \"/var/task/clients/pyppeteer_client.py\", line 32, in __create_browser_instance\n    '--user-data-dir=/tmp'\n",
        "  File \"/tmp/sls-py-req/pyppeteer/launcher.py\", line 311, in launch\n    return await Launcher(options, **kwargs).launch()\n",
        "  File \"/tmp/sls-py-req/pyppeteer/launcher.py\", line 125, in __init__\n    download_chromium()\n",
        "  File \"/tmp/sls-py-req/pyppeteer/chromium_downloader.py\", line 136, in download_chromium\n    extract_zip(download_zip(get_url()), DOWNLOADS_FOLDER / REVISION)\n",
        "  File \"/tmp/sls-py-req/pyppeteer/chromium_downloader.py\", line 125, in extract_zip\n    zf.extractall(str(path))\n",
        "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/zipfile.py\", line 1616, in extractall\n    self._extract_member(zipinfo, path, pwd)\n",
        "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/zipfile.py\", line 1662, in _extract_member\n    os.makedirs(upperdirs)\n",
        "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/os.py\", line 211, in makedirs\n    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)\n",
        "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/os.py\", line 211, in makedirs\n    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)\n",
        "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/os.py\", line 211, in makedirs\n    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)\n",
        "  [Previous line repeated 2 more times]\n",
        "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/os.py\", line 221, in makedirs\n    mkdir(name, mode)\n",
        "OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/home/sbx_user1051'\n"
    ]
}
```

Comment: please add some more info, as I can see the you do not have write permission in `/home/sbx_user1051`

Comment: i've added some context, please let me know if you need more information and what kind

Comment: dockerfile, pyppeteer config

Comment: okay, updated. also added serverless.yml

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to change `ENV PYPPETEER_HOME='tmp/'` to

```
ENV PYPPETEER_HOME='/tmp/'
```

it seems `PYPPETEER` try to `mkdir` in `/home/sbx_user1051/tmp` which has no `write` permissions in

Comment: Setting that environment variable returned...                                                                        
`"message": "Browser closed unexpectedly:\n/tmp/local-chromium/575458/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libXcursor.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory\n"`                                                                                
But I've solved my problem by uploading the chrome binaries through serverless' package include option. I just wanted to leave a response for future searches.

Comment: Could you expand on how you uploaded "the chrome binaries through serverless' package include option."? Thanks!