# requests_html render (async) not working on AWS Lambda Read-only file system

Tags: python, aws-lambda, python-requests-html

I have a Python script that scrapes data from a webpage.

It works on my local but not on AWS Lambda because it only allows writes new file to `/tmp` directory.

I tried to go through `request_html` `render` API and it seems like it's not possible to change the file location. It default take current working directory by default. It's causing error as below

Error detail `Read-only file system: '/home/sbx_user123'`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How's set an environment variable below from lambda web UI?

```
PYPPETEER_HOME=/tmp/
```

It may change working directory of pyppeteer (a module running inside request_html).

maybe, it's a related question: [Pyppeteer fails to download headless chrome when running on AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57650505/pyppeteer-fails-to-download-headless-chrome-when-running-on-aws-lambda)